# IntelliJ 12 debugger not working with grails application

Tags: debugging, grails, intellij-idea

I set a breakpoint in my BootStrap code. The debugger is obviously breaking on the line. However, it does not show the code highlighted in blue and the local variables are not showing up. This makes it awfully hard to do any debugging. Please see image below to see what I mean.

[image: screen shot of debugger]

I set my conf directory as the source path as suggested by Sergey. Now I am able to stop at the breakpoint in init() as shown below:
[image: breakpoint in init method]

However, when I try to step into one of the closures called by init(), execution goes off into some unknown fetchLatestIfExists code as shown below:
[image: unknown "fetch latest" code]

Comment: does debugging with print works?

Comment: I have no interest in debugging with print statements. I paid good money for IntelliJ and I expect it work.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't mean that way, I was just asking to make sure the code is really executing. It's just I've ran into some weird behaviors with intellij's debugger, when in doubt I go back to print statements just to see if the debugger isn't fooling me. It's a valid debugging technique. :)

Comment: 12.1.4 (latest) I confirm I was able to hit break points inside `BootStrap.groovy` both in default and in remote debugging. If you are not on the latest version then upgrade and try again. BTW how do you like Darcula?

Comment: Missed to mention that I was able to access local variables in the debugger as well.

Comment: I'm on intelliJ 13.x opensource and experiencing the same as this question describes when looking at source in an library (in this case the grails-core). The frames section indicates the app is stopping where I put the breakpoint, but the line in the source is not being highlighted, and as a result it's impossible to step through.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some plugin has BootStrap.groovy file too. IDEA cannot determinate which BootStrap.groovy is currently executed, because debug info contains file name only.
I can suggest two workaround:
1.) Mark $PROJECT_ROOT/conf as source root
2.) Move your initialization code to MyBootStrap.groovy. (Grails executes all $PROJECT_ROOT/conf/*BootStrap.groovy scripts on start)